# iOS SegmentedControl not responding to touch events when outside view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control that sits hidden behind the navigation bar, just out of view. When a button is pressed, I have the whole view animate downwards so it becomes visible, sliding out from the navigation bar. My problem is that it then doesn't respond to touch events, I think because it lies just outside the bounds of the view. Is there any way to extend the view upwards by 50px or so ?

In XCode the size attribute for the view is greyed out and unable to be changed.
Thanks.

```
CGRect mainFrame = mainView.frame;
mainFrame.origin.y = 40;
statusButton.action = @selector(hideStatusBar:);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"showStatus" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
statusButton.title = @"Status";
mainView.frame = mainFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Where have u added the segmented control ? as a subview to the mainView ?

Comment: Yes it's as a subview of the main view for this view controller. I've gotten around the issue temporarily by sliding down only the segmentedView, so that it sits over the mainView. It then works, so the problem must be something to do with whether or not it is positioned above the main view.